# Ubuntu hangs on purple screen at startup

Tags: boot

My pc works fine. I can boot it up properly but it always decides to get stuck on a purple screen for around 15secs. After this text "ubuntu" with the dots come up in a low-ish quality and then I can finally log in and do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is booting Ubuntu during those 15 seconds. You can see a detailed log of what was happening during boot by viewing the file `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: What should I look for in it?

Comment: Each line should contain a timestamp which gives you a view of what things were happening during boot. You can also look to see if anything is blocking the boot process like a network timeout or waiting on a piece of hardware. If you're not running an SSD a boot time of 15 seconds seems very reasonable. Before boot you can also hold down `Shift` and press E to modify the boot command in Grub removing the "quiet splash" options which will show you while booting exactly what is happening instead of showing the splash screen.

Comment: From `/var/log/syslog` I found a long line of `\00\00\00\00`. The line above this was `Sep 25 23:27:05 gottaslay kernel: [ 6168.928624] audit: type=1400 audit(1537907225.320:90718): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4706 comm="Discord" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"` and underneath `Sep 25 23:28:07 gottaslay systemd-modules-load[290]: Inserted module 'lp'`

Comment: `Sep 26 15:51:51 gottaslay systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...` It seems module "lp" has something to do with this? `Sep 26 15:52:39 gottaslay systemd-modules-load[292]: Failed to find module 'lp'`

Comment: So it seems that the computer stops to this `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` for the time being.

Comment: That means a driver/module is attempted to be loaded into the Linux Kernel that is not signed. You can try disabling "secure boot" in your BIOS as a workaround. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455189/pkcs7-signature-not-signed-with-a-trusted-key

Comment: I entered `sudo mokutil --disable-validation. ` in terminal and then did `mokutil --sb-state` to see whether secure boot is on or not and received `SecureBoot disabled`.

Comment: I am curious what the output of `sudo systemd-analyze blame` shows, since it should count time that is blocking the boot process. (eg. it may be possible the signature trusted warning/error isn't actually blocking the boot process but happens to be the last thing print)

Comment: Five highest lines are. ` 35.974s dev-sdb5.device`. `20.622s plymouth-quit-wait.service` ` 11.560s NetworkManager-wait-online.service` ` 3.470s apport-autoreport.service` `717ms systemd-journal-flush.service`

Comment: That means the boot process is spending 36 seconds waiting for your hard drive (sdb5) `plymouth-quit-wait.service` isn't actually blocking anything, it's waiting for other services to finish so it can finish the splash screens. You can also run this command to see a better breakdown of the boot process `systemd-analyze plot > output.svg`

Comment: I'm seeing nothing out of the ordinary here. https://files.fm/u/3rcb26nx I uploaded the file there if you could take a look?

Comment: After even further investigations it seems to get stuck to `Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage`